# Intersect buffer with vector to extract information

Tags: r, r-sf

This is my first attempt at doing GIS analysis in R so hopefully what I've done so far and my question makes sense.

I have a data frame of points within the UK which I have converted to a sf object and calculated a 250m buffer around each point. I also have some land cover vector data which I've also converted into a sf object. The land cover data is split into land cover types.

I would like to calculate the percentage of different land cover types found within each 250m buffer. I've managed to get what I think is the vector data for each buffer, but I'm not sure how to extract the information (i.e. area/proportion of each land cover type) from each buffer.

This is what I've got so far:

XY data below

```
require(rgdal)
library(mapview)
library(sf)

sites <- structure(list(plot = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 
72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 
109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
120L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 
181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L), 
    gridref = c("ST7498436114", "ST7492436114", "ST7486436114", 
    "ST7528433234", "ST7516436174", "ST7498436174", "ST7522433294", 
    "ST7468435994", "ST7516436054", "ST7504436054", "ST7498436054", 
    "ST7576432994", "ST7576533004", "ST7492436054", "ST7486436054", 
    "ST7480436054", "ST7522436114", "ST7474435934", "ST7468435934", 
    "ST7570433114", "ST7504435994", "ST7582432874", "ST7498435994", 
    "ST7576432874", "ST7492435994", "ST7570432874", "ST7486435994", 
    "ST7480435994", "ST7474435994", "ST7564435094", "ST7558435094", 
    "ST7546432934", "ST7420435514", "ST7420435574", "ST7426435694", 
    "ST7576432814", "ST7426435754", "ST7420435754", "ST7426435814", 
    "ST7486435025", "ST7612432874", "ST7607132839", "ST7588435034", 
    "ST7582435034", "ST7576435034", "ST7522435034", "ST7498435034", 
    "ST7582432754", "ST7581632758", "ST7576435094", "ST7570435094", 
    "ST7570432754", "ST7516434914", "ST7564432754", "ST7510434914", 
    "ST7489834968", "ST7594434974", "ST7594432694", "ST7597532791", 
    "ST7588434974", "ST7528434974", "ST7522434974", "ST7504434974", 
    "ST7606434854", "ST7546434854", "ST7552432694", "ST7540434854", 
    "ST7522434854", "ST7492434854", "ST7600434914", "ST7540434914", 
    "ST7618432694", "ST7534434914", "ST7558434734", "ST7552434734", 
    "ST7504434734", "ST7498434734", "ST7576432574", "ST7606434794", 
    "ST7564432574", "ST7558434794", "ST7546434794", "ST7496634827", 
    "ST7618432634", "ST7630434494", "ST7624434554", "ST7522434554", 
    "ST7516434554", "ST7618434614", "ST7618434674", "ST7612434674", 
    "ST7564434734", "ST7648434314", "ST7648434374", "ST7570432454", 
    "ST7642434374", "ST7642434434", "ST7636434434", "ST7636434494", 
    "ST7576432394", "ST7522433714", "ST7588432274", "ST7516433774", 
    "ST7522433594", "ST7540433534", "ST7546433474", "ST7534433474", 
    "ST7528433474", "ST7492436174", "ST7522436234", "ST7486436234", 
    "ST7534433354", "ST7480436234", "ST7498436294", "ST7516433354", 
    "ST7492436294", "ST7486436294", "ST7516436114", "ST7504436114", 
    "ST7492433834", "ST7498433894", "ST7504433714", "ST7504433474", 
    "ST7576432634", "ST7527336046", "ST7533436050", "ST7496835930", 
    "ST7491135929", "ST7536336131", "ST7532436239", "ST7546033412", 
    "ST7533433668", "ST7546733054", "ST7546033171", "ST7460735809", 
    "ST7455135810", "ST7492533597", "ST7516133894", "ST7611032751", 
    "ST7599532629", "ST7563133004", "ST7558533053", "ST7594132635", 
    "ST7600032936"), lon = c(-2.35882798600066, -2.35968529791987, 
    -2.36054260970957, -2.35434318476877, -2.35626020256111, 
    -2.35883216905146, -2.35520415532218, -2.36310607872696, 
    -2.35625189650525, -2.35796650101658, -2.35882380307907, 
    -2.34747232387985, -2.34745871838488, -2.35968110501236, 
    -2.36053840681614, -2.36139570849011, -2.35539873703486, 
    -2.36224456469475, -2.36310184613728, -2.34833723210959, 
    -2.35796232820981, -2.3466074559054, -2.35881962028668, -2.34746423080273, 
    -2.35967691223436, -2.34832100557515, -2.36053420405253, 
    -2.36139149574089, -2.36224878729914, -2.34932832124224, 
    -2.35018546484601, -2.35175219973381, -2.36992990937229, 
    -2.36993422091177, -2.36908560394007, -2.34746018445156, 
    -2.36908990589506, -2.36994715632925, -2.36909420798293, 
    -2.36046634739346, -2.34232357955569, -2.34307806730496, 
    -2.3458957145579, -2.34675284868196, -2.34760998268123, -2.35532418300805, 
    -2.3587527131752, -2.34659938326637, -2.34671388643665, -2.34761403365783, 
    -2.34847117751274, -2.34831289305932, -2.35617301455928, 
    -2.34916964776812, -2.357030127205, -2.35997665493164, -2.34503455939921, 
    -2.3448818567799, -2.34444568960825, -2.3458916836673, -2.35446291945093, 
    -2.35532004233278, -2.35789141020988, -2.34331230896304, 
    -2.35188334891386, -2.35087907083258, -2.35274045221757, 
    -2.35531176136585, -2.35959727405167, -2.34417342420112, 
    -2.35274456269774, -2.34145487458687, -2.3536016758543, -2.35016098122337, 
    -2.35101806482134, -2.35787472903205, -2.35873181148214, 
    -2.34744400029595, -2.34330830838447, -2.34915745002822, 
    -2.35016506151211, -2.35187924854011, -2.35899542001203, 
    -2.34145089838956, -2.33986012737858, -2.34072114258117, 
    -2.35529106118602, -2.35614811408587, -2.34158217774011, 
    -2.34158615799082, -2.342443232856, -2.3493038974994, -2.33727720150278, 
    -2.33728113125349, -2.34829261396095, -2.33813815683999, 
    -2.33814209668946, -2.33899913213172, -2.33900308208057, 
    -2.34743186349066, -2.35523311768249, -2.34571042235175, 
    -2.35609417888437, -2.35522484208367, -2.35265005375973, 
    -2.3517890723444, -2.35350281992438, -2.35435969352383, -2.3596894909569, 
    -2.35540702337447, -2.3605510158859, -2.35349458523648, -2.36140834751853, 
    -2.35884053554068, -2.35606514581882, -2.35969787741951, 
    -2.36055521916881, -2.35625604946904, -2.35797067395225, 
    -2.35952605843373, -2.35867330390757, -2.35780385700866, 
    -2.35778718664423, -2.3474480461475, -2.35469391232931, -2.3538225975963, 
    -2.35904376714229, -2.35985811443216, -2.35341379671676, 
    -2.35397847963346, -2.3518419625423, -2.35365895139517, -2.35171755255592, 
    -2.35182550302169, -2.3641931796262, -2.36499336018916, -2.35949523507335, 
    -2.35614532235317, -2.34251531682126, -2.34414928167033, 
    -2.34937223011837, -2.35003243626169, -2.34492074441706, 
    -2.34409838966173), lat = c(51.1237571019443, 51.123754466421, 
    51.1237518246133, 51.0978735338664, 51.1243044830452, 51.1242966140316, 
    51.0984104468623, 51.1226648376649, 51.123225458519, 51.1232202189951, 
    51.1232175898066, 51.0957360604064, 51.0958260221032, 51.1232149543339, 
    51.1232123125767, 51.1232096645353, 51.1237675811927, 51.1221279861883, 
    51.12212532568, 51.0968125396748, 51.1226807067568, 51.0946595744632, 
    51.1226780776186, 51.0946570295548, 51.1226754421963, 51.0946544783684, 
    51.1226728004898, 51.122670152499, 51.1226674982241, 51.1146139554378, 
    51.1146113898789, 51.0951837260487, 51.1183272329659, 51.1188667448915, 
    51.1199484791649, 51.0941175140535, 51.1204879909912, 51.1204852803661, 
    51.1210275027673, 51.1139596733116, 51.0946722048351, 51.0943552673697, 
    51.1140846411133, 51.1140821007327, 51.1140795540699, 51.1140563514, 
    51.1140458757624, 51.0935805433128, 51.0936161720752, 51.1146190677084, 
    51.1146165147143, 51.0935754474132, 51.1129747154744, 51.0935728900467, 
    51.1129720998063, 51.1134486332581, 51.1135476613768, 51.0930460983536, 
    51.0939196213418, 51.1135451273271, 51.1135194413093, 51.1135168381554, 
    51.1135089910009, 51.1124736826157, 51.1124481860401, 51.0930282410747, 
    51.1124456018318, 51.1124378115152, 51.1124247020154, 51.1130106752108, 
    51.1129851153262, 51.0930561644051, 51.1129825247864, 51.1113743081748, 
    51.1113717366288, 51.1113509381199, 51.1113483100386, 51.0919594515448, 
    51.1119341685333, 51.091954343383, 51.111913821918, 51.1119086724458, 
    51.1121837658749, 51.0925166484142, 51.1092466189503, 51.1097836374543, 
    51.1097402440333, 51.109737634947, 51.1103206495309, 51.1108601638605, 
    51.1108576551798, 51.111376873439, 51.1076355248773, 51.1081750396969, 
    51.0908778691438, 51.1081725626614, 51.1087120773832, 51.1087095940192, 
    51.1092491086431, 51.0903409041346, 51.1021870483868, 51.0892669548417, 
    51.1027239542518, 51.1011080196316, 51.1005762922147, 51.1000393606328, 
    51.1000341882122, 51.1000315925832, 51.1242939784578, 51.1248466057182, 
    51.1248308485354, 51.0989551588552, 51.1248282003419, 51.1253756380551, 
    51.0989473534293, 51.1253730023804, 51.125370360421, 51.1237649708073, 
    51.1237597311831, 51.1032529717066, 51.1037951193141, 51.1021792043864, 
    51.1000211472752, 51.0924989672475, 51.1231582609789, 51.1231968706504, 
    51.1221018957455, 51.1220903988326, 51.1239264662945, 51.1248959019189, 
    51.0994816900486, 51.1017781863846, 51.0962628852802, 51.0973146386257, 
    51.1209979188271, 51.1210044144558, 51.1011219350515, 51.1038028520133, 
    51.0935656115046, 51.092463770299, 51.0958203158045, 51.0962589537862, 
    51.092515448027, 51.0952245028064)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-144L))
```

Convert XY data to sf object and create buffer

```
sites2 = st_as_sf(sites,coords=c("lon","lat"), dim = "XY", crs=4326)
coords <- st_geometry(sites2)
st_crs(coords)

buff_coords <- st_buffer(coords, dist = 250)
mapview(coords) + mapview(buff_coords)
```

Land cover data [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b96bf9a75c3d27f3da8ea4692310892d20220930143321/521658)

Read in land cover data and use st_intersection to get land cover data within each buffer

```
land_cover <- st_read(
 "land_cover.shp")

buf_intersects <- st_intersection(buff_coords, land_cover)
buff <- st_as_sf(buf_intersects) # convert to sf object

mapview(coords, col.regions="red", cex=2) + mapview(buff)
```

This is where I've got to. It looks correct, each buffer has the vector lines within it.

What I'm struggling with is how to extract information from the buff object. I would like either area or proportion of each land cover type.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to consider is that the output of `st_intersection()` keeps the attributes of `x` whereas `y` is only used for clipping. Since `buff_coords` is of type geometry set without any attributes, your output only includes geometry information. That's why your result looks correct. What is missing, and what you are interested in, are all the attributes to calculate areas, so simply switch the inputs:

```r
st_intersection(land_cover, buff_coords)
#> Simple feature collection with 2153 features and 12 fields
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -2.373569 ymin: 51.087 xmax: -2.333649 ymax: 51.12766
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> First 10 features:
#> [...]
```

In order to determine proportions of land cover classes you might want to calculate areas of your classes within the buffer per site and use `aggregate()` to sum areas of the same class in order to get the weights desired.

I'm not quite sure if you can do this operation all at once, so I'll just show the workflow for the first site feature so that you should be able to construct a for-loop in order to iterate over all your features:

```r
# clipping lc data with buffer of first site
x <- st_intersection(land_cover, sites[1,] |> st_geometry() |> st_buffer(dist = 250))

# calculate area
x["area"] <- st_area(x)

# sum area per INTCODE
aggregate(area ~ INTCODE, x, sum)
#>   INTCODE               area
#> 1       1  49098.67741 [m^2]
#> 2       2 148094.15274 [m^2]
#> 3       3   2090.11273 [m^2]
#> 4       4     55.95573 [m^2]
#> 5       5     41.40524 [m^2]
```

**Edit:**

I also noticed the area does not quite add up to `pi * 250^2` and I guess this is a result of using `st_buffer()` and `st_area()` on a dataset with a geodetic coordinate reference system (EPSG: 4326). In order to reproject your data (land_cover & sites) to a commomly used projected system in your area of interest - I used WGS 84 / UTM zone 30N (EPSG: 32630) here, but you'll probably know better - you can make use of `st_transform()` resulting in desired values:

```r
a1 <- sites |> st_buffer(dist = 250) |> st_area()
head(a1)
#> Units: [m^2]
#> [1] 199380.3 199244.6 199278.6 199276.3 199343.5 199301.7

a2 <- sites |> sf::st_transform("epsg:32630") |> st_buffer(dist = 250) |> st_area()
head(a2)
#> Units: [m^2]
#> [1] 196259.8 196259.8 196259.8 196259.8 196259.8 196259.8
```

However, since you seem to be interested in proportions only and not absolute areas per se, I would not expect significant distortions here based on your radius chosen - but I'll probably still go for a suitable projected reference system.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much for your help. Quick Q - the total area per site in your example is ~199,000m2, but the maximum area in circle with a 250m radius should be ~196,000. Is this difference an issue?

Comment: @LHordley: You're welcome! I added a quick reply to my post, see above.